# Android notepad tutorial, part 2, step 3 - магия да и только!

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

[Вот тут](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex2.html) откройте пожалуйста Step 3. Если кто-то выполнял этот гайд и может объяснить, почему info.id - это первичный ключ из нашей бд, я буду несказанно счастлив!

Я, если честно, вообще не понимаю, какое отношение он имеет к базе данных, да и в описании шага написано:

```
The id field of this object tells us the position of the item in the ListView.
```

Это конечно бред. Если бы это было так, то при добавлении 2х записей и удалении первой вторую удалить было бы невозможно, но на практике можно добавлять и удалять любое количество записей, что еще больше вгоняет в ступор.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Хм, если вам сочетание "первичный ключ"(`PRIMARY KEY`) ничего не говорит, мб что-то скажет "основное поле сортировки"?)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не надо намёков :) Говорите прямо. Поиск по странице выражения "primary key" не дает никаких результатов. Я уже доделал третью часть до конца, но этого момента не понимаю, хотя борюсь с ней второй день. Очевидно, что я уже несколько нервничаю по этому поводу :) Так что пожалуйста, скажите прямо (если конечно знаете), кто, когда и как помещает в поле id первичный ключ из нашей таблицы :)

Вообще это какой-то бред. А что, если у нас первичный ключ - не счетчик, а text? :D Я конечно понимаю, что такого делать не стоит, но тем не менее =\

Comment: Тут дело в том, что это термин из SQL и к java он (как и я, гы) относится весьма опосредовано) Первичный ключ - поле, по которому "по умолчанию" сортируется БД и в файловой структуре он обычно располагается так, чтобы выборка по этому ключу была быстрейшей. То есть, да, вы можете удалять-изменять данные, но сортировка при этом не собъется. Если из набора (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) удалить пару записей, порядок останется (1, 3, 5). Про текстовый ключ - "сумевший задать вопрос знает ответ" =) Так делать не стоит, но уже зависимо от типа БД он по идее должен работать так же.

Comment: И да, вам лучше подождать кого-нибудь из java-кодеров, ибо я пишу все-таки "наиболее вероятное предположение".

Comment: Выборка при удалении идет по ключу, а не по номеру элемента в листе. Если не верите - могу код показать, но вы и сами можете это увидеть, если загляните в первый туториал.

Comment: > The id field of this object tells us the position of the item in the ListView.

Поле "id" этого объекта показывает нам позицию записи в ListView. Речь не о том, что запись "2" всегда будет второй. Речь о том, что запись "2" всегда будет перед записью "15".

Comment: Так что дальше то? :D нам нужно передать в mDbHelper.deleteNote значение поля id из таблицы! И только так) deleteNote - это просто DELETE FROM table WHERE id = " + id, который мы передали))) Она будет удалять по id из таблицы, она не будет удалять кортеж с id на 1 (на 2 или на 10) большим, если кортежа с нужным id не оказалось в таблице)) Какая разница, какой у нас порядок?)

Comment: Если отбросить  устоявшиеся ассоциации с термином "первичный ключ"(PRIMARY KEY) , то по моему все очевидно. Есть таблица, в ее строках есть поле id. По этому полю строки сортируются. 

Все.

Comment: Ок. Давайте так.

Таблица:

id value

1 а

2 б

В листе мы видим:

а

б

Удаляем первую запись - а. То есть в deleteNote передаем 1, всё клёва. Остается только б. Хотим удалить б. В честь чего теперь в deleteNote мы передадим 2? Ведь если мы передадим туда 1, никакого удаления не произойдет.

По-моему, вы просто издеваетесь надо мной :D

Скорее всего там какая-то высокоуровневая штука, которая сопоставляет элемент листа и id из базы данных. В каком месте это происходит я и хочу понять.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это, конечно, ошибка в примере. Доки андроида [ясно говорят](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo.html), что `id` в этом классе означает `id` записи - не зря `ContextMenuInfo` сначала приводится к `AdapterContextMenuInfo`, чтобы получить доступ к этому полю. А для позиции есть поле `position` там же.

Comment: Ну на счет выражения "ясно говорят" я бы поспорил - ну да ладно) Вы можете объяснить, каким образом в этом id оказывается id из таблицы? Я не могу найти объяснения даже в доках - не то, что в туториале, хотя по-моему это КРАЙНЕ важно :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208738/adaptercontextmenuinfo-id а вот и ответ. Спасибо за наводку)